# How to disable a button if no items displayed in a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have created a student enrolment wizard that they go through every year that uses the `MultiView` control and I have multiple `View` Controls within it. An example of one `View` control can be seen below;

```
<asp:View ID="address_view" runat="server">
    <h1>Address:</h1>
<asp:Button ID="add_new_address" CssClass="blue" runat="server" Text="Add New Address" OnClick="add_new_address_Click" />
<div id="add_address_div" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="address_dropdown_insert" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="Home">Home Address</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Term">Term Time Address</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Mail">Mail Address</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Business">Business Address</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList><br />
            Address 1:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="address_1TextBox" /><br />
            Address 2:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="address_2TextBox" /><br />
            Town/City:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="town_cityTextBox" /><br />
            County:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="countyTextBox" /><br />
            PostCode:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="postcodeTextBox" /><br />
            Country:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="countryTextBox" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" ID="InsertButton" OnClick="insert_address_button_Click" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" ID="Button4" OnClick="cancel_address_button_Click" /><br />
</div>
    <asp:ListView ID="address_list" runat="server" DataSourceID="user_address" DataKeyNames="address_id">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            // code here
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <br />
            <p>There are currently no addresses found, please click the button above to add a new address.</p>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            //code here
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            //code here
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

<br />
    <asp:Button CommandName="NextView" ID="Button1" Enabled="false" runat="server" Text="Next" />
</asp:View>
```

I have the following C# on `PageLoad`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Enabled = address_list.Items.Any();
    }
```

However, the button still appears even if there is no data in the ListView. 
My question is, how can I prevent a user from continuing onto the next view when they click `Button1` if their is no data in the ListView?

I'm fairly new to C# so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the value you are getting in "address_list.Items.Any()"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
if(address_list.Items.Count() = 0)
{
Button1.enabled = false
}else
 {
 Button1.enabled = true
 }
```

But have in mind that if you call this before you bind the data it wont work so be sure to not use this code as the first line in the Page load event

> The lv.items.Count() will return 0 if it has no rows after binded

Comment: Sorry i badly misunderstood the initial problem

Comment: This worked thank you, I had to edit the syntax a little as shown below
`if(address_list.Items.Count() == 0)
    {
    Button1.Enabled = false
    }else
     {
     Button1.Enabled = true
     }`

Comment: No problem :D glad to help.